# I need to move an image dynamically,depending upon the input from the user..What should i use?

Tags: android

Depending upon the user i may need to move it to right ,left,top or bottom.
Should i use animation for the purpose?
Or is there any method to move image dynamically?
I meant the things in android application

Comment: That depends on what kind of movement you're talking about. Is this going to be in response to a touch action or are you just some kind of button push/menu setting?

Answer (score 0):

You use animation for a movement that has a distinct start and stop point. For example you might move the image right to left at a button push. It would slide a cross the screen and then appear back at its original position.

If you wanted to move things around this way you could do so by having 2 (or more) copies of the same view.. hiding the view at the old position and showing it again at the new one. You generally won't be stopping this animation between its begin and end point.

If you want some more interactive movement (say move along with the user's finger on the screen), you'll need to make use of the canvas and some touch listeners. In that case I recommend looking up drag and drop samples as they address what is needed for this to happen (and then some).